# What is the equation of the quadratic function through $(2,5)$ with roots $1+\sqrt 5$ and $1-\sqrt 5$?

Tags: quadratics

Determine the equation of the quadratic function that passes through $(2,5)$ if the roots of the corresponding quadratic equation are $1+\sqrt 5$ and $1-\sqrt 5$.

Comment: Hint: The quadratic function has shape $k(x^2-2x-4)$.  Remark: Your post would be much improved if you indicated what you had tried.

Comment: hello sir, what do you mean by that

Comment: I found a quadratic whose roots are the given ones. The easiest way to do this is to recall that if the quadratic $x^2+bx+c$ has roots $r$ and $s$, then $b=-(r+s)$ and $c=rs$. Now please play with it for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the results of the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) is that every degree $n$ polynomial may be written in the form $f(x)=k(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$ where $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are the roots (*possibly complex and possibly repeated*).

You are told that you are working with a quadratic and that its two roots are $(1+\sqrt{5})$ and $(1-\sqrt{5})$.  You are also told that $f(2)=5$ as it passes through the point $(2,5)$.

These imply the following two things:

$f(x)=k(x-1-\sqrt{5})(x-1+\sqrt{5})$ and $f(2)=5$

Solving for $k$...

> we have $5=k(2-1-\sqrt{5})(2-1+\sqrt{5})=k(1-\sqrt{5})(1+\sqrt{5})=k(1-5)=-4k$

Implying that

> $k=-\frac{5}{4}$

Thus, your quadratic is:

> $f(x)=-\frac{5}{4}(x-1-\sqrt{5})(x-1+\sqrt{5})$

which can simplify if desired as

> $f(x)=-\frac{5}{4}x^2+\frac{5}{2}x+5$